# trying to setting up a php app

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have to copy this huge PHP app that lets user login and stuff.

I am totally lost as to what to do at this moment.
They gave me the whole website folder including the html files and everything in there
(over 1000 random files and tons of php files).

The database files consist of the following extensions.

```
.MYI .MYD .FRM
```

BUT they are in some encoding that I can't even import into a newly made database.

```
default-character-set=latin1
default-collation=latin1_swedish_ci
```

I keep getting errors on syntax.

I am totally new at doing this stuff, what are the normal steps in copying an existing
and working PHP application to a new location and getting it to work?

/edit

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'þþ' at line 1

����d�9�������� ���������H���H���mm}@)892T33333 @�333 @�333[...]

Comment: "errors on syntax" isn't going to get you any useful help. Can you isolate some of the errors and quote them here?

Comment: what are the errors messages?

Comment: Ask the developers!  They should have sent installation instructions!

Comment: well i have no idea how to setup this php application 
also the encoding of the sql files don't look too good

Comment: well i know php.. its just that there are so many files there i don't even know where to start on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the raw files for the database, Put them in the database data directory `(/var/lib/mysql/dbname)`

the FRM is the structure and the MYD is the data. They are the needed 2 as the MYI can be generated from them 2.

Make sure the mysql user can read and write to them (chown -r mysql:mysql)

Hopefully that should allow the import

As far as i know there is no way to do this in phpmyadmin but i could be wrong.

Also for best chances of this working I would stop mysqld and restart when your finished moving the data

Comment: It sounds like a very unconventional way NOT to distribute the initial db layout as a SQL dump, but as raw data files.

Comment: What a freakin' hairball. A candidate for http://WorseThanFailure.com/ Tell them to give you a mysql dump.

Comment: Agreed, Not a good way to transfer a database but im not sure the OP can do much about how the distribute

Answer (score 0):

The other answer here (from https://stackoverflow.com/users/1281385/user1281385) is absolutely correct.  These .frm , myi, and .myd files are the container files that the mysqld software uses to stash away its data, specifically for MyISAM access method files.

But I should like to offer a (possibly) more robust way of handling the problem.

Can you set up a local, personal, MySQL instance?  If so, please try to find out the exact version of MySQL your tormentor (er, customer) is using and set up that particular version.

Then put copies of the .frm, .myi, .myd files (not the originals!!), as user1281385 suggested, into the mysql data directory. They go in a subdirectory named for the database.  Start up the database server and see if you have what you need.

If you do, then use the command line `mysqldump` or some other migration tool to move the data gracefully to a new production server.

The technical term for what you need to here is "screwing around until it works."

A better solution would be to get your customer to give you `mysqldump` output, if that's possible.